# Java exception variable

Tags: java

Is there any way to access exception variable lenght in catch space?

```
    public class myexception extends Exception{
        public int lenght;
        myexception (int a){
            this.lenght=a;
        } 
}

try{
       if(something) throw new myexception (10);
} 
catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.lenght);}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, because `e` is of type `Exception` and not `myexception`, so it would not have any way of knowing what `lenght` is.

If you want that, then catch `myexception` instead of `Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to catch your specific exception:

```java
try {
    if(something) throw new myexception (10);
}
catch(myexception e){
    System.out.println(e.lenght);
}
```

See https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/